traefik get valid certificates for subdomains
I want to obtain a valid SSL certificate for both subdomains.
traefik.mydomain.app works correctly but arangodb.mydomain.app gets an unsafe warning.
Also, the http challenge does not work on arangodb.mydomain.app.
Other than that services are running correctly. The below is my docker-compose.yaml
PS. my domain is not really mydomain.app but it is .app and DNS records are set correctly.
version: '3.8'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.11
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - "--api.dashboard=true" 
      - "--api.insecure=false" 
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80" 
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443" 
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=${TRAEFIK_EMAIL}"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro" 
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt" 
      - "./shared:/shared" 
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`${TRAEFIK_DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.usersfile=/shared/.htpasswd"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.httpchallenge.rule=Host(`${ARANGO_DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.httpchallenge.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.httpchallenge.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    restart: always

  arangodb:
    image: arangodb:latest
    container_name: arangodb
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8529:8529" 
    environment:
      - ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=${ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - "arangodb3.12:/var/lib/arangodb3"
      - "arangodb3.12-apps:/var/lib/arangodb3-apps"
      - "arangodb3.12-backup:/backup"    
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.arangodb.rule=Host(`${ARANGO_DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.arangodb.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.arangodb.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.arangodb.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.services.arangodb.loadbalancer.server.port=8529"
    restart: always

networks:
  web:
    external: false

